# Word completely bugging when editing a shape

Tags: microsoft-word

in word 2007 I created a line on the background, but it expanded to the whole page (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>)and I opened the foramtting window of the line but I can't close it it says `Dimension must be between -57,87 and 57,87 cm`(translation is approximate). I can't do anything, if I cancel nothing happen, I confirm the message and select another tab still that message. I cant' close since I didn't saved it.

[image]

Comment: this guy didn't get an answer but mentions the same message https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.application.errors/oeU6j7wFsq0       "The measurement must be between 
-55.88 and 55.88"  Number is simlar to you. googling word shape "the measurement must be between" might lead somewhere. is there no way to change the "measurement" to being between?

Comment: @barlop OK, thank you. I sorted it out myself by closing the process and word recovered my changes. Microsoft did that, at least.

Comment: hmm, it'd have been interesting if you'd checked for a temporary file like word may call it ~...tmp or maybe ~...docx and hidden, and if you'd tried to copy that to blah.docx and open it, and see if that opens, then you'd perhaps have been able to know or predict before closing word, whether it had recovered it but anyway.